# MVC Unable to find a partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-apicontroller

I have two project (AccountController and OrderController), one is a controller and the other is an ApiController. The controller is the AccountController while the OrderController is the ApiController.

I need to access an action from AccountController (that sends a account confirmation email, transform a view into a string). This will happen when the user makes an order, when it detected that the user is new, it will auto-register it and then make a registration confirmation email (that's the responsibility on the AccountController.

Here's an excerpt on the OrderController

```
var context = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context);
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Account");
routeData.Values.Add("action", "Register");
var requestContext = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(context, routeData);
var controllerContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(requestContext, new AuthenticationController());
await AccountController.SendAddressRegistrationEmail(controllerContext,model);
```

Here's the part on the AccountController,

```
public static async Task SendAddressRegistrationEmail(ControllerContext context, model)
{
    var manager = context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var helper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);

    //// Generate the token and send it
    string encodedEmailToken = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(await manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(model.ID));
    string body = ViewAsString(context, "~/Views/Templates/RegistrationConfirmation.cshtml", new RegistrationConfirmationMessage
    {
        EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress,
        Expiration = expiration,
        ConfirmationUrl = helper.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = model.ID, encodedEmailToken = encodedEmailToken, ReturnUrl = returnUrl }, protocol: context.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, hostName: context.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host)
    });

    await manager.SendEmailAsync(user.ID, "Confirm your account", body);
}

protected static string ViewAsString<T>(ControllerContext context, string viewName, T model)
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, new ViewDataDictionary<T>(model), new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(context, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

FindPartialView is always returning NULL, the partial view is located on (Views/Templates/RegistrationConfirmation.cshtml).

Did I miss something that causes the partial view not visible when I made sure that the controller context is the AccountController? Or there is something on the "Context" needs to be initialize?

Comment: did you try adding the view in shared folder

Comment: @Ravi tried putting it on the shared folder but it's not working. Both controller (apicontroller and controller) is in a different project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate projects, where one is the normal MVC project, and the other one is an API project, then the view is definitely in the MVC project.

Check the namespace and assembly references: Ensure that the namespace and assembly references are correctly set up in the `RegistrationConfirmation.cshtml` file. The file should have the necessary `@using` directives and assembly references to access the required classes and models.